# DNS address not found after setting up redirect from Blogspot to custom domain

Tags: hyperlink, blogger

i'm having a bit of a problem, Blogger redirect to custom domain works from links but not from search bar( `www.abc.com`) works but (`abc.com`) doesn't

I recently purchased a domain(48 hours ago) to use for my Blogger site that was previously using the name abc.blogspot.com. I set up a redirect from the old domain to the new domain using Blogger's settings. The redirect works when I click on a link from the old domain, but when I enter the new(abc.com) domain into the search bar, I get an error message saying 'DNS address could not be found' for the new domain. How can I resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, i simply had to redirect the `example.com` to `https://www.example.com` in my domain's registar. A quick article explaining how to do this is [here](https://www.ajirarasmi.com/2023/04/how-to-redirect-non-wwwmasked-url-to.html)